# Same x509certificate in server and client

Tags: c#, cryptography, certificate, client-server, x509certificate

I have the same certificate (use x509certificate2) in the application and in the server (both in C#),

I have to extend the validity of the certificate file **in the server**,

I use in SSL3  with the certificate to connect to soap web service from client (with set or get)

My question Is it mandatory for the same certificate to be in the app?

```
  try
        {
            // Initiate a new request to the WS

            System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;

            MyServiceSSL.MyWebServiceClient clClient = new MyServiceSSL.MyWebServiceClient();

            clClient.Endpoint.Address = new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress(sConnStr);

            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateRemoteCertificate);

            try
            {
                clClient.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(
    StoreLocation.LocalMachine,
    StoreName.TrustedPeople,
    X509FindType.FindBySubjectName,
    "myDomain.com");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
              ...
            }

             MyServiceSSL.myDataRequest clRequest = new MyServiceSSL.myDataRequest();

            // Set up request parameters
            clRequest = new myDataRequest();

            clResult = clClient.myFunc(clRequest.MyRequest_1);
```

Comment: We need some more information on what you are trying to achieve with the certificate to help. Are you asking if you can get the certificate from the store?

Comment: I added, is it enough?

Comment: Using same certificate fro server and client is certainly not a good idea at all.

Comment: What is the other side of winForm client?

Comment: Is `clClient.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(` the [WCF certificate authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/transport-security-with-certificate-authentication) ? In this case you have to use one certificate for client and another one for service. I'm not sure about "extending the validity of the certificate". You can issue a new one if current expires.

Comment: Encryption needs a both a Private Key and Public Key.  The certificate is used to get the Private Key.

Comment: If I renew the certificate and install it not through the code, Must I have to compile again the winForm app?

Comment: the code you have shown searches for the certificate using the subject name "myDomain.com". It is code from MSDN sample I believe so for production purpose i'd like to propose to move certificate subject to the application configuration file (and you do not need any more to modify the source code with new cert names) or to use configuration file for the `MyWebServiceClient` endpoint hosting like it is [documented](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/transport-security-with-certificate-authentication). Then certificate name change will not need form compilation

Comment: I think you need to have a look at PKIX. Having the same certificate in both client and server is only required for self signed certificates, which is the simplest structure of implementing PKIX.

Answer (score 1):

> I have to extend the validity of the certificate file in the server,

Does that mean the validity date? If so, of course you need to **renew both** otherwise one would be *expired* and therefore not valid any more.

BTW: You should not use [SSL3](https://disablessl3.com/)